# Removing AM/PM, but keeping the 12h format

Tags: excel, time

I have an Excel workbook that calculates times using equations throughout the workbook.  A typical formula looks like this; "=A6+TDJT!$H$5"  Is there a way to display the times in 12h format without displaying the AM/PM at the end?

I've tried adjusting the custom formatting, but it either displays the 24h format or the AM/PM.

Comment: Would not such strange formatting bring in uncertainty about what datetime is displayed in target cell? it looks like result should be the date(but not interval). But if target value should be duration/interval, then probably HH:MM should be ok. Please edit your question to specify what values are in A6 and H5 and what is expected result, date or interval.

Comment: If you start at 11:00 AM and work for two hours you finish at 1:00 PM and saying just 1:00 can't be informative. If you start at 2:00AM and finish at 6:00PM you worked for 6 hours and writing 4:00 isn't correct. Please explain how a display in 12 hour format, meaning restart from 1 after 12 hours, can be logical.

Comment: No, there is not, unless you convert the times to text strings (in which case you would not be able to use them in calculations).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not, unless you convert the times to text strings (in which case you would not be able to use them in calculations). - Thanks to Ron Rosenfeld for this answer.